# Error adding contact in android

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am using Android Studio, code:

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(
    ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
    .withValues(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
    .withValues(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
    .build());
```

Error:

```
Error:(535, 17) error: method withValues in class Builder cannot be applied to given types;
required: ContentValues
found: String,<null>
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Screenshots:

[image: image1]
[image: image2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You choose the wrong method if you want to pass String and Object you should use

```
withValue(String key, Object value)
```

not the

```
withValues(ContentValues values)
```

**NOTE** notice the first one is without **s** and the second one you used in the code is using the one with **s**

see this for reference see
[withValue(String key, Object value)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProviderOperation.Builder.html#withValue(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)) and [withValues(ContentValues values)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProviderOperation.Builder.html#withValues(android.content.ContentValues))

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. That's stupid mistake on my part.